# How can i refactor multiple if conditions and multiple operators so that i can reduce code complexity in java

Tags: java, memory, code-complexity

I have a java code where i'm calling database function for data insertion.
Function may returns error code on the basis of exception in Database. To show those errors on the screen i have written bellow code.

```
String DBerrorCode=DatabaseReturnErrorCode;//Errorcode from Database

if("RUREF00001".equals(DBerrorCode)){
    throw new DataUpdateException(ErrorRUREF00001);
}else if("RUREF00002".equals(DBerrorCode)){
    throw new DataUpdateException(ErrorRUREF00002);
} else if("RUREF00003".equals(DBerrorCode)){
    throw new DataUpdateException(ErrorRUREF00003);
} else if("RUREF00004".equals(DBerrorCode)){
    throw new DataUpdateException(ErrorRUREF00004);
} else if("RUREF00005".equals(DBerrorCode)){
    throw new DataUpdateException(ErrorRUREF00005);
} else if("RUREF00006".equals(DBerrorCode)){
    throw new DataUpdateException(ErrorRUREF00006);
} else if("RUREF00027".equals(DBerrorCode)){
    throw new DataUpdateException(ErrorRUREF00027);
} else if("RUREF00028".equals(DBerrorCode)){
    throw new DataUpdateException(ErrorRUREF00028);
} else if("RUREF00029".equals(DBerrorCode)){
    throw new DataUpdateException(ErrorRUREF00029);
} else if("RUREF00030".equals(DBerrorCode)){
    throw new DataUpdateException(ErrorRUREF00030);
} else {
  //default error
    throw new DataUpdateException(DATA_INSERT_ERROR);
}
```

My requirement is to reduce multiple operators, if conditions,no more than 3 operators in on if statement and light weight code where less memory is used.

Kindly suggest if anyone have any creative solution.

Comment: Not answering your question, but you should have a look at [switch case](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html)

Comment: Are all `ErrorRUREF000XX` in one `enum`? Or how are they defined?

Comment: @DnyaneshwarPote Is your question resolved?

Answer (score 2):

I'll use a Map.

```
map.put("RUREF00001",ErrorRUREF00001);
map.put("RUREF00002",ErrorRUREF00002);
map.put("RUREF00003",ErrorRUREF00004);
```

---

And then you simply write a line that

```
throw new DataUpdateException(map.get(DBerrorCode));
```

---

*Side note : Java variable names starts with lower case letter.*

Comment: Thank you @ANS for your suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

```
for (int i=1; i<=6; i++){
    String s = "RUREF0000" + i;
    //Define your error
    if(s.equals(DBerrorCode)){
            throw new DataUpdateException(your error);
    }
```

the same for the i = [27,30]

finally you can put a if condition for the cases (i<1, i>6 and i<27, i>30)
as the default error

also you can define switch cases https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html

but this won't reduce your code length. It depends on what is your task

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, you may use a `Map` like other answers suggest .

Assuming the parameter (e.g `ErrorRUREF00001`) you pass to `DataUpdateException` is a `String` :

```
Map<String, String> errorMap = new HashMap<>();

errorMap.put("RUREF00001", ErrorRUREF00001);
// populate other values ....
```

Then you may have a method to check the mapped message, use that if one is found, use the other value if none is found :

```
public void manageError(final String dbErrorCode) {

    if (errorMap.containsKey(dbErrorCode)) {

        throw new DataUpdateException(errorMap.get(dbErrorCode));
    } else {

        throw new DataUpdateException(DATA_INSERT_ERROR);
    }
}
```

Finally instead of you `if` `else` statements, just call

```
   manageError(DatabaseReturnErrorCode);
```

Comment: map type is `<String, String>`. from this line -> `errorMap.put("RUREF00001", ErrorRUREF00001)`. What is `ErrorRUREF00001`?

Comment: @nazar_art : I'm assuming it is a `String` type, but you're right, added this precision to the answer.

Comment: Thank you @nazar_art for your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

For omitting `if-else` statements you can use [Enum](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html).

Your logic should be like below:

- get the string code value
- iterate over enum values with `Enum.values()`
- if string value match some error code -> `throw new Exception()` with this code, like parameter
- if no match throw default Error at the end.

Here is small demo:

```
enum ErrorCodes {
    RUREF_00001("RUREF00001"),
    RUREF_00002("RUREF00002"),
    RUREF_00003("RUREF00003");
    // ...
    private String errorName;

    ErrorCodes(String errorName) {
        this.errorName = errorName;
    }

    public String getErrorName() {
        return errorName;
    }
}

public class ErrorHandler {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String dbErrorCode = "ruref00003"; // get the error code from Database

        for (ErrorCodes code : ErrorCodes.values()) {
            if (code.getErrorName().equalsIgnoreCase(dbErrorCode)) {
                throw new DataUpdateException(dbErrorCode);
            }
        }
        //default error
        throw new DataUpdateException(DATA_INSERT_ERROR);
    }
}
```

---

Thus all your `if-else` statements will be replaced with few lines:

```
   for (ErrorCodes code : ErrorCodes.values()) {
      if (code.getErrorName().equalsIgnoreCase(dbErrorCode)) {
         throw new DataUpdateException(code);
      }
   }
```

It is much more elegant solution.

Comment: What about `valueOf(String)` ? but then we had to catch the `Exception` and rename the `ErrorCodes`

Comment: @Jérôme `valueOf(EnumClass, String)` is not the best idea. If the string wouldn't match enum constant you will have exception. Much better will be add string parameter to enum and compare with it. If no match default exception will be thrown.

Comment: Thank you nazar_art for your suggestion but; don't you think the code readability is being complex.

Comment: @DnyaneshwarPote It looks a little bit at this example. It contains 3 diffrent classes. Also, you will have separation of responsibility. Enum will hold error codes and you will have possibility easily check it value. Each class do its own job (responsibility). You can skip update for exception class, if pass only string value as exception parameter.

Comment: @DnyaneshwarPote you can appreciate answer by upvoting